# react-stripe-js button for pay always stays disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to follow the basic example from react-stripe-js documentation, however, I am stuck on a problem that I have been unable to figure out for a while.

My stripe "Pay" button always stays disabled, even when I enter the information that I have got from the stripe testing page - https://stripe.com/docs/testing.

My components:

CheckoutForm and InjectedCheckoutForm

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {CardElement, Elements, ElementsConsumer} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';


class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {stripe, elements} = this.props;
    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {stripe} = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <CardElement/>
        <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
          Pay
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export const InjectedCheckoutForm = () => (
  <ElementsConsumer>
    {({stripe, elements}) => (
      <CheckoutForm stripe={stripe} elements={elements} />
    )}
  </ElementsConsumer>
);

export default CheckoutForm;
```

ViewMembers.js that renders the Elements and Injected Checkout form just fine.

I have made some changes in my ViewMembers Component to try something new. I am setting a state value to null, and in the lifecycle method componentDidMount() I am assigning the promise object that I am using from the stripe, and now when I do `console.log()` for this state value I am also getting the fulfilled promise, but this promise is for some reason not being sent as a prop to my Elements component because my button in the CheckOutForm is still disabled.
*Another edit.

Actually the promise object is being sent, and I can see my API key when using React Dev Debug tools, however the button stays disabled even tho the prop of stripe receives the proper value.

````
class ViewMembers extends React.Component {
 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            members: [],
            isModalClicked: false,
            isModalClickedEdit: false,
            emptyList: false,
            id: 0,
            showStripe: false,
            stripePromise: null
 
 
        }
 
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.openModalEdit = this.openModalEdit.bind(this);
        this.closeModalEdit = this.closeModalEdit.bind(this);
    }
 
    openModal(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("the modal is being opened");
        this.setState({
            isModalClicked: true,
        }, () => {
            console.log("this state id", e.target.value);
            console.log("this state id", this.state.id);
        })
    }
 
 
    openModalEdit(e) {
 
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Edit modal is being opened");
        this.setState({
            isModalClickedEdit: true,
            id: e.target.value
        }, () => {
            console.log("this state id", this.state.id);
            console.log("this state id", this.state.id);
        })
    }
    closeModalEdit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Edit modal is being closed");
        this.setState({
            isModalClickedEdit: false
        })
    }
    closeModal(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("The modal is being closed");
        this.setState({
            isModalClicked: false
        })
    }
    fetchingMembers = () => {
        var id = this.props.id;
        console.log("this props", this.props.id);
 
        axios.get(`https://localhost:44345/api/gyms/${id}/members/`)
            .then(res => {
                const members = res.data;
                this.setState({ members });
                console.log("Members", members);
 
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
 
    openPaymentStripe = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
 
 
        this.setState({ showStripe: true })
 
 
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchingMembers();
        const stripePromise = await loadStripe('stripekey');
 
        console.log('stripe promise', stripePromise)
        this.setState({
            stripePromise: stripePromise
        })
    }
 
 
 
 
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
            axios.get(`https://localhost:44345/api/gyms/${this.props.id}/members/`)
                .then(res => {
                    const members = res.data;
                    this.setState({ members });
 
                    console.log("members", members);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
    }
 
 
    renderTableData() {
        if (this.state.members) {
            return this.state.members.map((member) => {
                return (
                 <TableRow key={member.id}>
                        <TableCell>
                            <label for="memberName">Member Name: {member.memberName}</label>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <label for="memberName">Member SurName: {member.memberSurName}</label>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <label for="memberName">Member Active Status: {member.isActive.toString()}</label>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <button value={member.memberID} onClick={this.openModalEdit}>Edit Member</button>
                            {/* <EditMember  isModalClickedEdit={this.state.isModalClickedEdit} takeClickEdit={this.closeModalEdit} GymId={this.props.id} MemberId={this.state.id}/> */}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <button value={member.memberID} onClick={this.openModal}>Add Member</button>
                            <AddMember isModalClicked={this.state.isModalClicked} isModalHidden={this.state.isModalClicked} takeClick={this.closeModal} GymId={this.props.id} onAddMember={this.fetchingMembers}/>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                )
            })
        }
}
 
render() {
 
 
       if (this.state.isModalClickedEdit){
           return (
               <EditMember  isModalClickedEdit={this.state.isModalClickedEdit} takeClickEdit={this.closeModalEdit} GymId={this.props.id} MemberId={this.state.id} onEditMember={this.fetchingMembers}/>
           )
       }
 
 
       if (this.state.showStripe){
       const stripePromiseData = this.state.stripePromise;
       console.log('stripePromiseData', stripePromiseData)
 
        return (
            <>
                <Elements stripe={stripePromiseData}>
                    <InjectedCheckoutForm />
                </Elements>
 
            </>
          )
    }
 
 
 
    const emptyList = this.state.members.length;
 
        if (emptyList == 0){
            return (
                <>
                <CircularProgress color="secondary"/>
                <button onClick={this.openModal}>Add Member</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
 
                <button color="primary" onClick={this.openPaymentStripe}>Purchase Membership</button>
                <AddMember isModalClicked={this.state.isModalClicked} isModalHidden={this.state.isModalClicked} takeClick={this.closeModal} GymId={this.props.id} onAddMember={this.fetchingMembers}/>
                </>
              )
        }
 
        return (
            <div class="container" className="ListOfGyms">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>List of Members</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Table id='gyms' class="table table-purple">
                    <TableBody>
                        {this.renderTableData()}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
                <button color="primary" onClick={this.openPaymentStripe}>Purchase Membership</button>
            </div>
 
        )
 
 
    }
}
 
 
export default ViewMembers;```
````

Comment: Sounds like the promise from `loadStripe` is never resolving. Are you passing in a valid publishable key? If so are you getting an error in your console?

Comment: I am passing a valid publishable key yes.This is what I am getting when console logging the promise - https://imgur.com/TT8nNQ8. Not an error.